# Increase pipe internal buffer size on CentOS

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, ipc, pipe

I'm using asynchronous pipes for inter-process communication (I removed error checks for simplification)

```
int pipe_fd[2];
pipe(pipe_fd);
int fdflags = fcntl(pipe_fd[1], F_GETFL, 0);
fdflags |= O_NONBLOCK;
fcntl(pipe_fd[1], F_SETFL, fdflags);
```

I'm looking for a way to increase pipe internal buffer size.
I know that it is possible to do with Kernel >= 2.6.35
by the following way:

```
fcntl(fd, F_SETPIPE_SZ, size);
```

or by writing to:

```
/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size
```

But I'm working on CentOS 5 with Kernel 2.6.18.
Is it possible to increase pipe internal buffer size with Kernel 2.6.18? If yes, how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the kernel of CentoS 5, a pipe is fixed at 64 KB

Answer (score 0):

Unless you only want to do this in your C code, one option is to use ulimit -p in a wrapper shell script that runs your program after setting the limit.

Comment: `-p     The pipe size in 512-byte blocks (this may not be set)`. Also, the value shown by ulimit is the max size that a write is guaranteed to be atomic. On the kernel of CentoS 5, a pipe is fixed at 64 KB.

Comment: In fact I'm wondering how shell does this. I'm guessing the "may not be set" covers the cases when the OS does not support altering pipe size.

Comment: OK, I will recompile Kernel in order to change pipe size

Answer (score 0):

```
/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size sets the limit for fcntl F_SETPIPE_SZ
```

just changing `/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size` makes no diference
`ulimit -p` also is useless

you must actually use `fcntl F_SETPIPE_SZ`

from what I've seen `pipe-max-size` default is 1MB, which should be more than plenty for any crazy pipe needs

Comment: can /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size be modified to increase the maximum pipe limit beyond 1MB? I have a crazy need for which I need it to be bigger then 1MB :)